# Change default button returned output of Applescript (from Bash shell)

Tags: bash, button, return, applescript, display

I am trying to customize the text returned in my terminal after pressing "OK" on an alert prompt. I am calling AppleScript from a Bash terminal using osascript.

When I run the following in bash:

```
osascript -e 'display alert "hi"'
```

I get the following result in my terminal:

```
button returned:OK
```

How can I customize that result to say something like "You just clicked ok" instead of "button returned:OK"?

Thanks!

Comment: The name of the button is what is returned by `osascript`.  You can change the name of the button or edit the returned text.

Answer (score 0):

When executing an AppleScript from the command-line, `osascript` will print to `stdout` the result of the very last operation performed by the script.  In the case of `display alert`, the result is a `record` with a single property, `button returned`, the value of which indicates the name of the button that was pressed.

If you want the output of `osascript` to be different, then you need to amend your script in such a way that its last operation returns the result that you want.  For example, knowing that `display alert` will return a result of the form I just described, we can use this as the basis of an additional line of code that makes use of it as part of a string containing the name of the button that was pressed.  As this will become the final line that executes, it dictates the text printed back to the terminal.

These three example AppleScripts will all do the same thing:

```
set phrase to "Very well! Give him "
tell (display alert "Cake or Death?" buttons ¬
        ["Cake", "Death"]) to get the phrase ¬
        & the button returned
```

```
"Very well! Give him " & the button returned ¬
        of (display alert ("Cake or Death?") ¬
        buttons ["Cake", "Death"])
```

```
display alert "Cake or Death?" buttons ["Cake", "Death"]
set button_name to the result's button returned
return "Very well! Give him " & the button_name
```

To use with `osascript`:

```sh
osascript <<-'OSA'
    "Very well! Give him " & the button returned ¬
            of (display alert ("Cake or Death?") ¬
            buttons ["Cake", "Death"])
OSA
```